# Using Power BI for Merging 4 Different Tables With Different Initial Starting Dates Into Additional Single Table : Feasible?, if yes, how

Tags: powerbi, merging-data

I have been directed to ascertain the feasibility of using Power BI for merging four different tables with different initial starting dates into an additional single table :  Each of these four tables involves an ongoing project of monitoring and inspecting a different set of work activities to check whether different hazardous materials involved in these four separate work projects are being properly contained and removed, and taking corrective action if indicated.

Although these different work projects each involve different specific work activities, the performance measures and procedures and methods which are used to check up on and monitor them are similar.

Our inspections of Project # 1 started in January of 2018; and, our inspections of Project # 2 started in June of 2019; and, our inspections of Project # 3 started in November of 2019; and, our inspections of Project # 4 started in march of 2020,

We have four different Excel tables, one for each of these four different projects, each with regular entries over time of evaluating the degree of succesx oif our inspections amd any corrective actions taken.

These tables are to be imported into Power BI reports.

However, we also want to combine these four different tables into a new single table with all of the entries of the four existing tables

Would this to be feasible despite these four different projects starting dates?

If it is feasible, then please instruct me how to do this.

Comment: Yes you can simply merge them if all of them have same columns. If different, you can still merge them and later you can define how to visualize things. for both case, you can add an indicator column with project name so that you can separate them easily, Better you share sample data from your 4 project.

Comment: is it possible for you to provide top 10 rows from your tables in order to write syntax of merge?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.